# Want to create a "side bar" at Crystal Reports overlaping all sections

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm trying to add a "side bar" to my report that can overlap all the other sections. Is there a way to do this? I can't find anything like that.
Also, this side bar will only have static text. So using the overlap bug/feature from details section will not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using CR2008 or later, you can underlay a section:

Add a new report header (right click report header and 'Insert Section Below')
In the section expert, select the new report header section and select 'Underlay following section'
This will spill the report header 2 over any groups, details and report footers so you may have to be careful with the size.

Design will look like:

[image: Image of design]

When previewed it will look like:

[image: Image of preview]

Comment: Except that will only print the sidebar once, on the first page. I assumed, possibly incorrectly, that the sidebar needed to appear on every page.

Comment: In my opinion a better option to print the sidebar on every page is to duplicate the page header section and add the sidebar there, then you only have to worry about the height of your textbox not exceeding the page rather than adjusting for pageheader/report header ect.

Comment: Agreed, I over-complicated and botched my origianl answer, so I'm just going to delete it.  And for what it's worth, you can underlay sections in CR 8.5 (don't ask).